# Google Cloud VM doesn't allow public ssh connections

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am running a Compute Engine VM in Google Cloud.

When I set up the instance, I pasted a public key into the Security section. Now that the instance is running, I can see that public key on its page in Google Cloud console (so it was saved and is associated)

However, I cannot `ssh` into the instance from my terminal. I opened Google's ssh client in the browser and saw that the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file does not have my public key in it.

I manually edited  `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` to add a line with the same public key that is shown in the Google Cloud console on this instance, and found that I could connect from my terminal. But as soon as I terminate Google's in-browser ssh session, `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` is reset and public ssh connections are blocked.

How do I allow public ssh connections to this instance?

Comment: What is the error-message? Are FW-rules (allow) in place?

Comment: @ppuschmann how do I check the forwarding rules? And the error message of external connection is `Permission denied (publickey).`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mention that ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file does not have your public key in it, this might be related to OS login activated at instance or project level.

Follow [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access#enable_oslogin) to disable OS Login if enabled, as explained in the warning for this step:

**Caution: Enabling OS Login on instances disables metadata-based SSH key configurations on those instances. Disabling OS Login restores SSH keys that you have configured in project or instance metadata.**

If this is not the problem, you should **collect and share your logs:**

1. Go to `Compute Engine` -> `VM instances` -> click on NAME_OF_YOUR_VM -> at the VM instance details find section `Logs` and click on `Serial port 1 (console)`
2. Reboot your VM instance (if possible).
3. Check full boot log for any errors or/and warnings.
4. **If you found errors/warning related to disk space** you can try to resize it accordingly to the documentation [Resizing a zonal persistent disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#resize_pd) or follow this article [Recovering an inaccessible instance or a full boot disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#inaccessible_instance).
5. If you require more help, share the full log by using [pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/).

Comment: Your link doesn't point out how to check if OS Login is enabled

Comment: It looks like following option 1 [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access#console) (but replacing TRUE with FALSE) may have fixed it

Comment: I linked to that guide because it is the step to enable or disable OS Login, based on that, you just had to disable it if it was enabled, just like you did by replacing TRUE with FALSE, my answer was edited to have a better description of that step. Remember to upvote or accept the answer if it was helpful.

Comment: Is the full log from Serial port 1 safe to share?